# Barracuda Bouncing Emails

Tags: email, email-server, email-bounces, barracuda

I'm not too familiar with all the intricacies of email servers and am curious what you guys think this looks like.
Is the receiving blocking it or is this something on our end?
The receiving company has stated that they have whitelisted our IP and they do not route to any websitewelcome.com nameservers. (We use Bluehost for our email)

```
Reporting-MTA: dns; gateway31.websitewelcome.com
X-Postfix-Queue-ID: 9B5CB2C9D77
X-Postfix-Sender: rfc822; xxx@ourdomain.com
Arrival-Date: Mon,  5 Apr 2021 12:09:51 -0500 (CDT)

Final-Recipient: rfc822; xxx@domain.com
Original-Recipient: rfc822;xxx@domain.com
Action: failed
Status: 5.0.0
Remote-MTA: dns; xxxxxx.ess.barracudanetworks.com
Diagnostic-Code: smtp; 550 permanent failure for one or more recipients
    (xxx@domain.com:550 Sender IP reverse lookup rejected)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Reporting-MTA` has tried to send a message to the `Remote-MTA` which has rejected the message with an error described in `Diagnostic-Code`.

The error `550 Sender IP reverse lookup rejected` is most likely related to SMTP [Reverse DNS Resolution](https://mxtoolbox.com/problem/smtp/smtp-reverse-dns-resolution) which is further related to a [Reverse DNS Mismatch](https://mxtoolbox.com/problem/smtp/smtp-reverse-dns-mismatch) test.

Answer (score 1):

```
550 Sender IP reverse lookup rejected
```

You need to have your ISP create a PTR record for your mail server, for the IP you are sending mail from.